# How do I access MediaQuery information on materialApp?

Tags: flutter

How can I access `MediaQuery` information on top of MaterialApp?

I need the height and width information of the device

CODE :

```
    final height =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; // I WANT TO REACH THIS !!!
    final width =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; // I WANT TO REACH THIS !!! IN HERE
    

    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: Home(),
      
    );
  }
}
```

THIS IS ERROR :

> FlutterError (No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.
> MyApp widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor.
> The specific widget that could not find a MediaQuery ancestor was:
> MyApp
> The ownership chain for the affected widget is: "MyApp ← [root]"
> No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you have not added a WidgetsApp, CupertinoApp, or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.)

---

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`MediaQueryData.fromWindow`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html) in this case.

```dart
final queryData = MediaQueryData.fromView(WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.implicitView!);
final height = queryData.size.height;
final width = queryData.size.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyApp1(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let `App` either be `MaterialApp`, `CupertinoApp` or `WidgetsApp`.

Normally `App` creates a `MediaQuery` and makes it available to its decendants. Because of that there is no `MediaQuery` available for ancestors of `App`.

You can however create your own `MediaQuery` ancestor which gets it's data from the `window` using `MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window)`. You then need to listen to metrics changes (e.g. window resize) and update the `MediaQuery` with the updated `MediaQueryData`.

Example:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MediaQueryProvider extends StatefulWidget {
  const MediaQueryProvider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MediaQueryProvider> createState() => _MediaQueryProviderState();
}

class _MediaQueryProviderState extends State<MediaQueryProvider>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    super.didChangeMetrics();
    // Initiate a rebuild of the MediaQuery with new MediaQueryData
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window),
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        // You can now get the MediaQuery of context.
        final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
        return const MaterialApp(useInheritedMediaQuery: false);
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell from such a small code excerpt, but I assume you are calling this in a `build()` method. MediaQuery are created by specific widgets, including WidgetsApp and MaterialApp. `MediaQuery.of` looks **up** the subtree from your widget which **includes** a MaterialApp, it does include one as an ancestor (up the tree).

You can fix this in a couple of ways, and they will likely improve your app's performance. One solution is to create the MaterialApp in your `main()` method and include everything else in your build code in the home() widget as a **child** of the MaterialApp. That way, the entire MaterialApp will not be rebuilt as often.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}
```

You can remove the MaterialApp from your build method

```
final height =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final width =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

print('H: $height  W: $width');

return Home();
```

This runs are prints out the width and height.